# How to remove horizontal line at zero in coefplot in r?

Tags: r, fixest

I have created this plot using the following code:

```
coefplot(list(
  feols(inc_ratio ~ provtariff | hhid02 + year,
        subset(inc_0206_spouse_p, Female == 1 & educ > 9 & year == 2002 | year == 2006),
        weights = ~hhwt, 
        vcov = ~tinh),
  feols(inc_ratio ~ provtariff | hhid02 + year,
        subset(inc_0206_spouse_p, Female == 1 & educ > 5 & educ < 10 & year == 2002 | year == 2006),
        weights = ~hhwt, 
        vcov = ~tinh),
  feols(inc_ratio ~ provtariff | hhid02 + year,
        subset(inc_0206_spouse_p, Female == 1 & educ < 6 & year == 2002 | year == 2006),
        weights = ~hhwt, 
        vcov = ~tinh)), main = "Effect of BTA on women's relative income \n(by eduction level)")
legend("bottomleft", col = 1:3, pch = 1, lwd = 2, cex = 0.7, bty = "n", 
       legend = c("Agriculture", "Wearing apparel and leather", "Manufacturing"))
```

[image]

Is there a way I can either remove the horizontal line at zero or making the horizontal line dotted?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: There are several packages with a `coefplot()` function — which are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the `fixest` package - though based on my understanding, it would be in the `legend` part of my code which is just base R

Comment: Would it work to just paint a white line on top of the black one and then repaint the erased chunk of the red one on top or do you need to do this repetitively?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `zero = FALSE` in the coefplot() function:

```
coefplot(zero=FALSE, list....)
```

Or if you want to add dotted line:

```
coefplot(zero.par = list( type="l", lty=2), list...)
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, it just took away the legend

Comment: You must add zero=FALSE immediately after coefplot(zero=FALSE, list....)

Comment: Thanks, that worked to remove the line - do you know how to change the line to dotted?

Comment: I updated my answer please have a look